# which pattern for a class with two attribute that depend from the other

Tags: design-patterns, typescript

I want to create an macro item. This macro item will be editable.

Each macro item has a type and an eventValue.

There is three type of items (pressKey, releaseKey, delayInMs)

For the pressKeyEvent and the releaseKeyEvent I want that the user can only select a keyObject as eventValue.

For the delayEvent I want that the user can only select a integer as eventValue.

for now I have this

```
export enum MacroEventEnum {
    pressKey,
    releaseKey,
    delayInMs
}

export class MacroItem {
    // This represent the type of the macro event
    public macroEvent: MacroEventEnum;
    // This represent the value associate with the macro event
    public macroEventValue: any;

    constructor(macroEvent: MacroEventEnum, macroEventValue: any) {
        this.macroEvent = macroEvent;
        this.macroEventValue = macroEventValue;
    }
}
```

The problem is that when the user change the type of the macroEvent to be a pressKey, it can still use a time as macroEventValue.

What kind of pattern should be used in this case knowing that the user can always change the macroEvent.

Thanks for your suggestions :)

Comment: "knowing that the user can always change the itemEvent" what does that mean? Also, is this homework?

Comment: is that more precise? @AlexHall

Comment: I don't know what language this is so I'm going to pretend it's Java. Are you planning on letting the user write `MacroItem item = new MacroItem(pressKey, enterKey); item.macroEvent = delayInMs;`? That's a very bad idea. You should make the class immutable.

Comment: You should always include the tag of the programming language in question.

Comment: I Added it. If I use an immutable class I will have to create a new every time the user want to change a macroEvent?

Answer (score 0):

You need a hierarchy of classes: `MacroItem`, `KeyMacroItem`, and `DelayMacroItem`, where `KeyMacroItem` and `DelayMacroItem` both inherit from `MacroItem`.

`MacroItem` has the `macroEvent` attribute, `KeyMacroItem` has the `keyObject` attribute additionally, and `DelayMacroItem` has the `delayValue` attribute additionally. You can have a virtual method in `MacroItem` that is overridden in `KeyMacroItem` and `DelayMacroItem` to behave in accordance to each their own requirement.